# android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm having an issue in using `CameraX`. When I call the function ImageCapture.takePicture, it doesn't return. I've tried on real phones and `Nexus S API 31` emulator. I've also put this question on `CameraX Samples` ([Link](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/547)). Your help will be appreciated.

**CAMERAX VERSION** (1.2.3, tested on 1.3.0-beta01)

**DEVICE NAME**: (Infinix Note 12 Android 12.0, 11.0)

**Code Snippet:**

```
imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun
                        onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them

                    }

//
                }
            }
        )
```

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE:**

1. Create Emulator Nexus S API 31
2. ImageCapure.takePicture
3. it goes in pending state

**OBSERVED RESULTS:**
Camera goes in pending state

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**
onImageSaved or onError should return

**Exception:**

```
Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating:
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2350)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1277)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:579)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.close(SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.java:476)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.release(CaptureSession.java:526)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.releaseSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:555)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.resetCaptureSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1329)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.closeCamera(Camera2CameraImpl.java:468)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.reopenCameraAfterError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1827)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.handleErrorOnOpen(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1779)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1754)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:121)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1748)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.$r8$lambda$KBQCqQRdhVVn7uHI9Xdha6OqnsU(Unknown Source:0)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```